# How can I copy/paste base64 images?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, highcharts

So I am using Highcharts.js which produces SVG charts. I convert it into PNG and then display it as an img on my page. But for some reason, when I try to copy the new image, the paste is empty.

```
$("#export").click(function() {
var svg = $("#chart").find('svg')[0];
var svgSize = svg.getBoundingClientRect();
var svgData = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString( svg );

var img = document.createElement('img');
document.querySelector('#image').src  = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(svgData)))
```

});

I can open up the image in a new tab but there's no right click copy option there. I can save the image. But for some reason, I can't get a copy?

EDIT: I'm not actually using the canvas. That was for something else. I did some more research on it and I saw a stackoverflow from several years ago about how the binary data images/ base64 images can't be copy pasted. Is there a solution around it?

Here is a sample JSFiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/lauralindy/8x9ob2v3/

Comment: That is because you are rendering it to the canvas.  Once drawn to the canvas, it becomes part of the canvas as it is drawn in immediate mode - dropping reference to the img once drawn.

Comment: Would it be possible to create a minimal jsfiddle or similar?

Comment: SVG is and XML based image format, meaning it is code. If you want to copy the SVG you can inspect the element and copy the whole `svg` tag. Otherwise, you'll need to convert it to a different format like (jpg, gif, png) and then copy it.

Answer (score -1):

You can copy an image created from `base64` string. Take a look at the example posted below. Click on 'Add image from a `base64` string' to append an image to the body tag, right click on the image, copy graphic, open some graphic editor and paste the image there.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/8j8p2uyk/